# How to block addon domain directory access

Tags: .htaccess, cpanel

I have a primary domain in a hosting. Let's say that domain is `example.com`

Then I added a new domain on that hosting. Let's say the new domain is addressed at `example2.com`

So in cPanel generate:

```
/home/index.php
/home/example2.com/dir/
```

If someone accesses my site like this: `example.com/example2.com/`
Then the displayed is my site that is located at `example2.com`

How to block access `example.com/example2.com/` and `example.com/example2.com/dir/file/test.html`

But if the site `example2.com` is accessed directly does not raise a problem?

I hope there is a solution using `.htaccess` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using an .htaccess

```
# Redirect example.com/example2
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^example2\.com$ "https\:\/\/example\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

OR

```
# Return a 403 response for example.com/example2
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^example2\.com$ - [R=403,NC,L]
```

Comment: Try using this in your example.com's .htaccess

Redirect 301 /example2.com http://example.com